# ASP.NET MVC 4 - MapRoute configuration to remove '/Home' where already exists default configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a solution, where the initial and default (RouteConfig) page is 'Login/Index'. This page, where name lets understand is used to user make login on system. After successful login, be redirected to Home page.

Login page the url showed is http://localhost:7037/ and after this, in 'Home' page is http://localhost:7037/**home**. How configure to controller Home in action Index dont show "home" on link? In other words, to working equal Login.

I tried some alternatives, and I still not find a solution to work in this specific case.

Thanks

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new [] { "Solution.UI.WEB.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Sorry what's exactly is your question? You want to redirect to /home on successful login?

Comment: You can not call two action from single url. either you can call home controller or login controller.

Comment: @ssilas777 Redirect to 'Home' is working, but, url show '/home'. I need remove this '/home'. The question perhaps has been confused because I explains the whole situation.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I need change to make 'Home' is default 'url', and via code redirect to Login if user does not have Session? It is a legacy system, built in a way a bit strange.

Comment: if you want to Home as default controller, change controller to "Home". On index action of Home you can check session. If session is empty, redirect to Login controller

Comment: You cannot have 2 default routes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood the problemn

You have one Route "Default" only.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new [] { "Solution.UI.WEB.Controllers" }
        );
```

What you have to do to "Home" disappear on Url is  change the controler "Login" to "Home" on "defaults". It Will be like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new [] { "Solution.UI.WEB.Controllers" }
            );
```

So, inside the Action "Index" on HomeController.cs you verify if the user is logged, if don't, you redirectToAction("Index","Login").

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try via javascript `replaceState` on your Home View

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var path = document.URL.match(/\/\w+(?=\?)/g)[0];
        window.history.replaceState('string', 'Some Title Text', path.replace('/',''));
    })();
</script>
```